# Creating PdfWriter Object?

Tags: itext

I want to write a simple code that will generate a pdf file. While following steps given by http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/f2e803/basic-pdf-creation-using-itextsharp-part-i/. I am unable to create an object of PdfWriter class. The following is the error code that occurred while creating PdfWriter object.

```
'iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfWriter.PdfWriter(iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfDocument, System.IO.Stream)' is inaccessible due to its protection level
```

Comment: That constructor is protected; you will have to call a different one.

Comment: Thank you Steven, i have used another constructor and it worked.

Comment: @Shujat he man what constructor did you use in order to open a PDF file? Thanks for the help.